# Fetching data from Firebase Database in previous Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I create applications using Firebase, Kotlin, Android Studio and Fagments with ViewModels. I'm not using any server.

In one of the Fragments I display a list of friendly users using the *viewModel.fetchFriends()* function where *addListenerForSingleValueEvent()* is located, which of course triggered when the fragment is created.
However, I would like the earlier Fragments to show the icon that someone new accepted our invitation and we have a new user in the list of friends.
Can somehow call the *fetchFriends()* function in an earlier Fragment? or maybe I should declare *fetchFriends()* in an earlier Fragment and pass the fetched data to target Fragment when navigate?
Which method should be used in these types of situations?

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared view model that is passed along the various fragments you're navigating.

There's a complete example of this situation in the [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) documentation page.